# How to test Rails Engine models with miniskirt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, miniskirt

I've run into a snag while trying to test a Rails 4 engine using miniskirt.

I have a model test set up in `test/models/job_manager/job_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

module JobManager
  describe Job do
    before do
      @job = Factory.build(:job)
    end

    it "is a valid object" do
      @job.valid?.must_equal true
    end
  end
end
```

My miniskirt factory is currently defined as:

```
module JobManager
  Factory.define :job do |j|
    j.title 'Job Title %d'
    j.description 'Lorem ipusum dolor sit amet consecateur ad piscin'
  end
end
```

And the error I get is:

```
uninitialized constant Job
Exception `NameError' at:
```

… which traces back to line 6 in the model test (`@job = Factory.build(:job)`). Replacing it with `@job = Job.new` works fine, but then I'm not using miniskirt factories any more. I get this error whether the factory is defined in the `JobManager` module or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per Stephen Celis, `Factory.define` doesn't use the current scope to resolve constants. This solved the problem:

```
Factory.define :job, class: JobManager::Job do |j|
  j.title 'Job Title %d'
  j.description 'Lorem ipusum dolor sit amet consecateur ad piscin'
end
```

See https://github.com/stephencelis/miniskirt/issues/19.